# jQuery Function not working once deployed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using a jQuery script I found online for dragging and dropping a gridview control. When I run the page in debug mode through visual studio, the functionality works perfectly.  When I deploy to the server and open the page using the same browser, the functionality ceases to work.

I do not get any error messages.  I commented out the library tags for testing purposes and I get an error message that jQuery does not exist. That indicates to me that the libraries and function are loading with the page, but are not working on the control.

I am using IE11, and I am using the same PC/browser when I open the page from the server.  The scripts are in the HEAD tag of the master page, though I have tried putting them into the content page.  The functionality works when I open in VS.  I verified that the class name cgvBidderClass is not changed when rendered by the server vs the local host.

I am hoping someone can help me identify why this is occurring.

```
<script src="/Javascript/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Javascript/jQuery/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Javascript/jQuery/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".cgvBiddersClass").sortable({
            items: 'tr:not(tr:first-child)',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            axis: 'y',
            dropOnEmpty: false,
            start: function (e, ui) {
                ui.item.addClass("selected");
            },
            stop: function (e, ui) {
                ui.item.removeClass("selected");
            }, <-- EDIT This comma was causing the issue!
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: not working means `$(document).ready` not been called?

Comment: I am not sure how I would validate that.  I assume that could be what it means.  When I try to move the rows, the text gets highlighted.  And I don't get any messages that indicate that something is not working.  The only clue I have is the rows do not drag & drop.  I am not sure how to test that...

Comment: you could add `alert('document ready!')` in `$(document).ready`, if the alert box jumped out on your deployed website, the problem probably happened in `$(".cgvBiddersClass").sortable`

Comment: I added the alert to the function, and it fires from local host, but not when I deploy.  I changed the $(document).ready() to $(window).load(), and got the same result.  What would cause the function to not get called?

Comment: Pro debugging hint:  Using `jshint` (or even `jsliint`) would have found this for you.   I'm sure that IE (in quirks mode) would have left a message in your console over that issue too. Not sure about strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was an additional comma that was causing the issue.  I removed the comma, and viola!

Thank you MarkoCen, your response helped me find the issue!